# detaching database results in error "SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to detach a database and I'm getting this error :

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:234; actual 0:0).
>   It occurred during a read of page (1:234) in database ID 5 at offset 0x000000001d4000 in file 'D:\Path\MyDB.mdf'.
>   Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail.
>   This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately.
>   Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 824)

What is the problem with this database file ? Other DBs are working well, only this one gives me this error.

Comment: Odds favor corruption due to IO hardware problem, could be transient or rare. What was the result of `DBCC CHECKDB`? What did you find in SQL Server Books Online? Often these kinds of problems require restoring from backup; be prepared to do that if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Torn page usually. Do you have backups? DBCC *may* be able to fix it though

The king of DBCC is Paul Randal: to avoid my copy/paste, read these from him

- [SQL Server 2008: Automatic Page Repair with Database Mirroring](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-Automatic-Page-Repair-with-Database-Mirroring.aspx)
- [Whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/7/a/47a548b9-249e-484c-abd7-29f31282b04d/SQLIOBasicsCh2.doc)

And search his site too for "logical consistency"

Comment: than you @gbn, I restored my DB by creating it again.